# Why does VueJS 3 doesn't render any elements when using axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using VueJS 3 together with vue-router and axios

In the rendered page there aren't any elements inside #app:

```
<div id="app" data-v-app=""><!----></div>
```

My route:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: "/:variableToPassTo",
        component: componentName,
        props: true
    }
```

My App.vue:

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

And component script code:

```
<script setup>
import axios from "axios"
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue"
...
let datas = {}
const props = defineProps([
    ...
])
onBeforeMount(await axios.post('...', 
    ...
).then(function (response) {
    datas = response.data
    console.log(datas)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
)
</script>
```

Also, in component template (HTML part), I used the `datas` variable

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that when you perform the `POST` API-call via `Axios` (which I assume that works), the response of it will be prompted in the `Console` of the browser that you use. This means that you can see your output in the `Console` window - the response won't be rendered (if I can recognize this right from your code well), which you can activate in your browser if you right-click inside it and from the menu choose the `Inspect` option. Then go to the `Console` tab which is the second tab from left to right (the first tab is the `Elements` tab) and control the response that came back from the api call.
In case you want to render the response in the template, then go to your `componentName` component and in your `HTML`-template do something like this:

**UPDATE:** Try to perform a `GET` api call, because a `GET` api call always returns a response. I've added a minimal code snippet, adapt it to your needs and tell me if it worked.

**main.js**

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import router from "./router";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://yourURL"; // either http or https

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(VueAxios, axios)
  .use(router)
.mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="router-nav">
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**componentName.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
name: "ScriptName",
data() {
    return {
      datas: []
    };
},
created() {
   performApiCall();
},
methods: {
   async performApiCall() {
     await this.axios.get("/pathApi").then((result) => { // change pathApi to the path that you use
        this.datas = result.data.output; // replace output with the signature response of the api response
      });
  }
},
}
</script>

<template>
<div>
  <p>
     {{ datas }}
  </p>
</div>
</template>
```

The response should be rendered in the template now.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, the problem is that I'm using that method and everything looks perfect; but still I don't get any output in div#app

Comment: @vueprogrammer please see my updated answer and let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `let datas = {}` and then updating it once axios resolves, but Vue has no idea it has changed.

You should use https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive since you're using composition API.